# Parse a CSV file to TCL

Tags: csv, tcl

I have a file as below:

```
a, b, c, d, e
S, 1.0, 100, F, fast
T, 2.0, 200, S, slow
```

First ROW is header only (a, b, c, d, e) and 2nd, 3rd row is the value (S, 1.0, 100, F, fast) correspond to the header.

I  would like to read the file below into tcl and puts out the values (ie: row 2, column 5 -> fast)

I wrote the below script but doesnt seem to work:

```
proc game {name infile outfile} {

    set csv [open $infile r]
    set csv_lines [read $csv]
    set out [open $outfile w]
    set info [split $csv "\n"]

    set infocount [llength $info]
    set line 1

    foreach line $info {
        set values [split $line ","]
        set firstline [lindex $values 0]
        set secondline [lindex $values 1]


    ### HOW DO I PUTS OUT ROW2 COL5 or ROW1 COL3 ###
       puts $outfile "$firstline"
    }

    close $infile
    close $outfile
}
```

Want outfile to be as below:

```
a: S b: 1.0 c: 100 d: F e: fast
a: T b: 2.0 c: 200 d: S e: slow
```

or

```
a: T b: 2.0 c: 100 d: F e: slow
a: S b: 1.0 c: 200 d: F e: fast
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do:

```
package require csv

proc splitline {fh} {
    if {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
        set fields [csv::split $line]
        return [lmap field $fields {string trimleft $field}]
    }
}

proc transform {file} {
    set fh [open $file r]
    set head [splitline $fh]
    while {[set fields [splitline $fh]] ne ""} {
        puts [join [lmap h $head f $fields {string cat $h ":" $f}]]
    }
    close $fh
}

transform "file.csv"
```

```
a:S b:1.0 c:100 d:F e:fast
a:T b:2.0 c:200 d:S e:slow
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try out all the script and see if it does what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`csv` package](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.md) from tcllib is the way to go for robustness, but on trivial data like this, [`split`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/split.htm) will work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

proc game {name infile outfile} {
    set in [open $infile r]
    set out [open $outfile w]
    set header [split [gets $in] ,]
    while {[gets $in line] > 0} {
        foreach col $header val [split $line ,] {
            puts -nonewline $out "$col: $val "
        }
        puts $out ""
    }
    close $in
    close $out
}

game foo input.csv output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Shawn for the script. I see the script is putting out the outputs incrementally. What do I need to do, if I have to print out on the value on the same line... S 1.0  100  F fast or T 2.0 200 S slow or T 1.0 100 F fast

Comment: I see you updated the question with what you want the output to actually be - I had to guess earlier. Will try to update answer when I have time tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `dict` to store the data of the csv file:

```
proc game {name inFile} {
    upvar csv_data csv_data        
    set csv [open $inFile r]
    set csv_lines [read $csv]

    set row 0

    foreach line [split $csv_lines "\n"] {
        set values [split $line ","]
        for {set col 0} {$col < [llength $values]} {incr col} {
            dict set csv_data $row [expr {$col+1}] [string trim [lindex $values $col]]
        }
        incr row
    }

    close $csv
}

set csv_data {}
game foo input.csv
```

Now you can read from the dict like the below, where row 0 contains the headers, and col 1 is the one with `a` as header:

```
# To get row 2 col 5:
puts [dict get $csv_data 2 5]
# => slow

# To get row 1 col 3:
puts [dict get $csv_data 1 3]
# => 100
```

To print in the other format you asked, you'll need to do a little more work:

```
set outFile [open output.txt w]
for {set row 1} {$row < [llength [dict keys $csv_data]]} {incr row} {
    set lineOut ""
    foreach {- header} [dict get $csv_data 0] {- value} [dict get $csv_data $row] {
        lappend lineOut "$header: $value"
    }
    puts $outFile [join $lineOut " "]
}
close $outFile
```

output.txt:

```
a: S b: 1.0 c: 100 d: F e: fast  
a: T b: 2.0 c: 200 d: S e: slow
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try it out and see if I can get it going.